# How to replace string value to mode in python?

Tags: python

I have a code and output as follows

```
df_train['SES'].value_counts()
```

Output is:

```
2    9186


1    5832


3    3279


?     446


4     383


Name: SES, dtype: int64
```

I want to replace `?` with mode which is 2 in this case and I wrote following code, at first look at output, it seemed the code worked, but when I ran the code again to see the value counts, I found it has assigned another 2 to `?` Here is the code and output:

```
df_train['SES'].replace('?',2, inplace= True)
```

Again I ran the code to check the value counts and found two different 2

```
df_train['SES'].value_counts()
```

And output is:

```
2    9187


1    5832


3    3279


2     445


4     383


Name: SES, dtype: int64
```

You can see that there are two different 2s , please any advice why it happens and how can I fix the problem?

Comment: Try doing this: `df_train['SES'].replace('?','2', inplace= True)`. Notice that `2` is a text now